# org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring

I am newbie to spring MVC and i am trying to render my first page of application.i am stuck with this problem since a week .please consider my code and let me know the solution .i am using maven project,I am getting the following exception: **org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource** 
My configuration is:

**Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>freeEducationProvider</groupId>
      <artifactId>freeEducationProvider</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>freeEducationProvider Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <finalName>freeEducationProvider</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

**Controller**

```
    package com.bookprovder.loginController;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public ModelAndView showLoginPage(){

            ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("loginForm");
            return modelAndView.addObject("headerOfPage", "Welcome To Free Education provider ");
        }

    }
```

and Spring-Dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
            htp://www.springframework.org.schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.bookprovder.loginController"/>

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springfraework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" ><value>/WEB-INF/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**loginForm.jsp**

```
<html>

<body>
    <h1>#{msg}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know the reason behind this exception and solution to get rid from this.

Comment: Please paste full stacktrace

Comment: `htp://www.springframework.org.schema/beans` isn't a valid UI... Use `http://` instead.